# while using appium inspector in order to automate my tests application get crashed at the moment of login

Tags: android, macos, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium

I'm using appium inspector in order to automate my test cases from Mac OS connected with a real device(Android).
At the moment of login to the app, a white screen is displayed and app get crashed! 
But the same action is working fine while i do it manually!

```
Date: Thu Jan 07 11:55:20 GMT+01:00 2016

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1377)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1395)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:637)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:616)
    at com.gtl.kemific.activity.DashboardActivity.loadWatchlistFragment(DashboardActivity.java:240)
    at com.gtl.kemific.activity.DashboardActivity.onClick(DashboardActivity.java:309)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You can not do anything if app is getting crashed / not responding. Collect the logs and report the issue to developers and relax ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it supposes to be an issue from developers.

Comment: Yeah ! But verify adb logs for the specific issue which is causing app close/ crash/not responding.

Comment: now not the app is getting crashed but the mobile screen becomes dark, i 'm obliged to reboot it every time this scenario happens.
This scenario is realted to the fact that i'm switching app from English To Arabic version in the login screen.